# Code flow with library method. Output not as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mern

[**what I am trying to achieve**]:  upload a set of images, then return image name,and resized image name

I have a code to resize oversized images. Why is my code in producing output as expected? in that oder.

In my below the output is:

```
before
after
resize_image_outputpath
```

but i want it :

```
before
resize_image_outputpath
after
```

```
app.post('/upload', upload.array('file'), (req, res) => {
var imagelist = [];

(req.files).forEach(function (file) {
    if (file.mimetype == 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype == 'image/png') {
        imagelist.push([file.originalname, __basefolder  + file.originalname]);
        var sizeOf = require('image-size');
        
        console.log("before");
        sizeOf(__basefolder + file.originalname, async function (err, dimensions) {
            if (dimensions.width > 128 && dimensions.height > 128) {
                const resize_2 = await resizeImage1(__basefolder, file.originalname, dimensions, 2);
                imagelist.push([resize_2, 2+"___"+file.originalname]);
            }
        });
        console.log("after");
    }
});
res.json(imagelist);
const file = req.file;
```

});

```
//resize images. reduce image size as per divisor value.
async function resizeImage1(folder, fileName, dimensions, divisor) {
    console.log("resize_image_outputpath ");
};
```

Comment: Why would you expect this code to run in a different order?

Comment: corrected my original post. I want to upload a image, and return image name + resized image name. So i want console  output like before , resized, after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question:

> Why is my code in producing output

You're iterating over the files in your request. As you do so, you first call:

```
console.log('before')
```

Then you call `sizeOf()`. It schedules the callback that you pass to execute later, on some other stack.

Then you call:

```
console.log("after")
```

Then the callback that you scheduled is executed, and you hit `resizeImage1()` which calls:

```
console.log("resize_image_outputpath ");
```

So that is why your output is:

```
before
after
resize_image_outputpath
```

I'm not sure why you'd expect `console.log("after")` to execute before `console.log('before')`, given that the code executes top-down, with exception of the async-scheduled callback.

---

**Edit**

You could try something like:

```
app.post('/upload', upload.array('file'), (req, res) => {
var imagelist = [];

(req.files).forEach(async function (file) {
    if (file.mimetype == 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype == 'image/png') {
        imagelist.push([file.originalname, __basefolder  + file.originalname]);
        var sizeOf = require('image-size');

        console.log("before");
        await new Promise(resolve => {
          sizeOf(__basefolder + file.originalname, function (err, dimensions) {
              if (dimensions.width > 128 && dimensions.height > 128) {
                  const resize_2 = resizeImage1(__basefolder, file.originalname, dimensions, 2);
                  
                  imagelist.push([resize_2, 2+"___"+file.originalname]);
              }
              resolve()
          });
        });
        console.log("after");
    }
});
res.json(imagelist);
const file = req.file;
```

This will yield the logs in the order you expect.

Comment: thanks for highlighting..   corrected my original post. I want to upload a image, and return image name + resized image name. So i want console  output like before , resized, after